# When to start clustering of Java EE Servers

Tags: jakarta-ee, load-balancing, jboss7.x

I'm running an application on JBoss 7.1.1 using Java EE 6, EJB 3.1, CDI, JSF 2 and Hibernate.

How do I know whether one standalone instance of a Java EE AS is enough to process all the requests or whether multiple instances of an AS are necessary?

How many requests per second should JBoss 7.1.1 be able to handle (in the general case)?

One time in a year the number of requests increase significantly and the server (that time it was JBoss 4.2.3) was failing. And I am not able to say whether it was due to poor design of the application or just due to big amount of requests.

Comment: there is no way to answer how many request JBoss will be able to process successfully without knowing what your software does, how it is designed, what hardware you are running on.
You should stresstest your software and monitor the jvm and cpu-load while doing so to find out how it is behaving memory and cpu-wise...

Comment: Retag: This is actually called [tag:load-balancing], not [tag:cluster-analysis]. Please tag more carefully (there is more than one term "clustering"!)

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple constant number (42 is not the answer for all). its depend on a lot of factors. long of request connections with database. process in the background.

you should read on load stress test (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_testing). 
you can create load test with JMeter (http://jmeter.apache.org/) or another tool and simulate peek time and average time.
try to simulate your request similar as you can to production request.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find out whether there are any specific requests that are performed mostly at that time of the year.

You can then run some **jmeter** tests for the specific requests (simulate multiple requests per second to application) in parallel with having attached **jvisualvm** in your jboss instance.

You can try these tests with many different jvm memory settings (e.g. *-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m*), and if possible with differrent numbers of processors (easier if you are on a Virtualized environment)

Supposing that your application can handle a lot of requests at the same time,
there is a setting in **urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1** subsystem of *standalone-ha.xml*
through which you can increase the max number of concurrent connections jboss can handle:

```
<connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" max-connections="10000" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
```

Finding the optimal max-pool-size / blocking-timeout-millis values for your datasource in *urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0* section may also prevent jboss from failing when your requests increase.

Combining the results that you get from the above tests you can then decide upon having extra instances of jboss running in a separate nodes.